# Head stylesheet and google code

Tags: html, css

my question ... if this is the "normal"way to include a .css stylesheet :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="highslide/highslide_min.css" />
```

and this is the code to be include to use normalize.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
```

The question is why using href and src ??? i am lost... i am like to change src for

Comment: My god, i found error in google documentation, what a great day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src` is an error in the documentation on Google Code. `href` is correct.

(I have [filed a ticket to get this fixed](https://code.google.com/p/normalize-css/issues/detail?id=2))

The [normalize.css homepage](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) does not point to a CDN.

Comment: Yep, Quentin's right. You can check it out [in the specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=feed#the-link-element), too.